# Getting property values of list of child objects

Tags: c#, reflection, properties

Let's say I have a `Car` class with some properties. One of the properties is an `IEnumerable` of another class, `Passenger`, with it's own properties.

```
public class Car
{
   public string Engine { get; set; }
   public int Wheels { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<Passenger> Passengers { get; set }
}
```

I am able to get the values of the Engine and Wheels properties (and all others such properties). However, I can't figure out how to get the properties of all the `Passenger` objects. Here's what I'm doing to get the property values of a `Car` object:

```
Type type = car.GetType();
PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();

foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
{
   object carValue = property.GetValue(car, null); 
   Console.WriteLine(carValue.ToString());
}
```

This obviously doesn't give me the `Passenger` properties, but outputs something like this instead:

```
System.Collections.GenericList'1[Passenger]
```

How do I grab all the property values of every `Passenger` in the `car.Passengers` list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with a mix of [`Type.IsGenericType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Type.GetGenericTypeDefinition()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
private void DisplayObject(object obj)
{
    var type = obj.GetType();
    foreach(var propertyInfo in type.GetProperties())
    {
        object value = propertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null);
        if(propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsGenericType && 
            propertyInfo.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>))
        {
            foreach(object o in (IEnumerable)value)
            {
                DisplayObject(o);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to check whether the property of `Car` is an `IEnumerable` first and if it is, then you will have to again use reflection on it. this can better be done using recursion as below:

**Your Car Object:**

```
public class Car
    {
        public string Engine { get; set; }
        public int Wheels { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Passenger> Passengers { get; set; }
    }
```

**Sample Application:**

```
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var car = new Car
            {
                Engine = "1234",
                Wheels = 4,
                Passengers = new List<Passenger>
                {
                    new Passenger
                    {
                        Id = 1,
                        Name = "Bhushan"
                    }
                }
            };

            ReflectObject(car);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

**Functions Used:**

```
        private static void ReflectObject(object objectToReflect)
        {
            foreach (var propertyInfo in objectToReflect.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                object propertyValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(objectToReflect, null);
                if (IsEnumerable(propertyInfo))
                {
                    foreach (object obj in (IEnumerable)propertyValue)
                    {
                        ReflectObject(obj);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(propertyValue);
                }
            }
        }

        private static bool IsEnumerable(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
        {
            return propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsGenericType &&
                     propertyInfo.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>);
        }
    }
```

**Output:**

1234

4

1

Bhushan